# ShrinkWrap issues

Tags: uv-image-editor, shrinkwrap, remesh

So I have a highpoly mesh that i exported from Zbrush. I also exported the polypaint as well, which comes with an image texture.

To lower the polycount, i decided to shrink wrap the mesh onto a lower poly model, however after shrinkwrapping, the polypaint does not appear on the shrink wrapped model

any suggestions?

I quad remeshed the second model but when I try to apply the UV Map to the new mesh, thats the result. Is there a way to use the same UV Map.

[image: Just the regular mesh with the polypaint attached]

[image: This is after I added the shrinkwrap to the low poly mesh, i attached the same image texture but the color is not appearing]

Comment: Edit your question to answer the following: "polypaint does not appear on the shrink wrapped model" ... are you saying that the original mesh no longer has the material?  Or that the new low-poly mesh doesn't have the material?  I think you mean the former, as the selected object in 2nd picture has a different object name...  why don't you add/apply the material from original object to the new object?

Comment: Another approach: try to Edit the first object and "Mesh :: Clean Up :: Decimate" (lower fraction reduces vertex count more).  See [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/295937/111042)

Comment: @james_t i updated my question, i think i left out some valuable info.

Answer (score 0):

Edit the first object and "Mesh :: Clean Up :: Decimate" (lower fraction reduces vertex count more).

here's a high-poly character in Edit mode:

[image]

Select the Decimate item:

[image]

and here I reduce by 80% (1.0 - 0.2):

[image]

and voila, the UV map is properly handled so that the original material is still properly mapped.

Comment: Would this method work for animating the mesh as well?

Comment: @LLovingKenny -- this should work well for both Armature animation, and also Shape Keys (the new vertices assigned will be recalculated appropriately).