# how to unwrap loose geometry in blender?

Tags: modeling, texturing, uv

Hi i have an object that i want to unwrap the UV's so the texture looks nice and real on it but the problem is that my object contains several other disconnected meshes within it , the Unwrap command doing pretty well actually but the problem is that it doesn't keep the texture rotation and i need to rotate the texture manually (rotating the separated mesh uv's to match te rest of the model ), i also don't have time to remodel these things since it takes too much time , also i have a second question that im researching for a while , is it possible that we make another surface and wrap it around our object like a cylinder or something like that then project uv's from that lower res object to our complex object ? (like projecting textures (actually baking them) ) also i have another question , in terms of a film asset creation is it true that we use mesh intersections like the one you see that i uploaded here or we need to forcefully merge them and retopologize them for better correct result ?

- also a brief update of what i want , maybe there should be a way to align the island properly in UV editor automatically .
- also i want that uv projection so bad ...
  [image]

Comment: You should make a question per topic to get a well planned answer to each of your issues. UV unwrap is mostly manually, you will have to spend time make it the way you need it, there are third party add-ons to help you, but still you will need to spend time manually fixing things to get your final goal

Comment: @Emir thanks Emir , back then i had some basic questions here , but unfortunately because of appearance of some reputation looters who don't even know anything about software my questions never get the answer , also the questions i have asked above are relative to the subject and if you don't have the knowledge about the software and you also wanted to loot reputation here please leave this question for someone who knows the answer .

Comment: If I wanted to "loot" reputation, I wouldn't recommend you to follow the way stack works. Probably 10 years of knowledge is not enough to answer your question. Thanks for the advice and have a good day

Comment: @Emir im pretty sure there should be a way or plugin that can align disconnected UV islands with same orientation as the others there could be

Answer (score 0):

your 2nd question: " we make another surface and wrap it around our object"

Two approaches:

1. research the shrinkwrap modifier.  You'd need a mesh with sufficient vertices so as to mold and lo-res to hi-res object.
2. My approach when getting spandex-like clothing onto a character... You can duplicate the hi-res object and then Edit :: Clean up :: decimate by 0.3 ratio or something more severe (lower ratio number), and then use a Surface Deform modifier to bind it to the original mesh (if needed for animation purposes).

Check this [image] out, where a cube mesh (subdivided for more vertices) is SD'd to a sphere that has shape keys:

[image]

Comment: tahnks james_t i was hoping there would be an easier method just one button project the UV , just like texture projection , i appreciate the answer btw it'll add stuff to my knowledge

Comment: @hamed.design -- unfortunately for all of these complex, arcane modeling software, there are few one-click solutions!